# Is there a way to "extend selection" like ReSharper in Visual C++ 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

I miss the "extend selection" in ReSharper, which automatic extends selection to expression, code block, function, class while you keep pressing Ctrl+W. The best that Visual Studio 2010 can do is SelectCurrentWord. I wonder if there is an add-on for such a functionality in Visual C++? This would ease operations such as selecting code block and method moving.

ReSharper's Extend Selection:
http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/webhelp/Coding_Assistance__Extend_Shrink_Selection.html